# Atbash Cipher in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption

To preface, I'm quite new to JS so my error may be embarrassingly elementary.

I'm trying to make a decoder for the Atbash cipher, which simply inverts the alphabet. Z=A, Y=B, so on.

Here's what I've got:

```
decode("ZYX");
function decode(message) {
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var tebahpla = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
var decoded_string = "";

for (i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    var coded_letter = message.charAt(i);
    var letter_index = alphabet.indexOf(coded_letter);
    var decoded_letter = tebahpla.charAt(letter_index);
    decoded_string = decoded_string + decoded_letter;
}
return decoded_string;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  I tried your decode function on "ZYX" and it came back with "ABC".

Comment: Why don't you just find the index of the letter in the alphabet string / convert it to an array for both. Then use the index to print out the or append to the decoded string with the tebahpla[index].

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CifradoAtbash {

public String EnAtbash(String mensage) {    

    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String tebahpla = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
    String alphabet1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String tebahpla1 = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
    String decoded_string = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < mensage.length(); i++) {
        char coded_letra = mensage.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(coded_letra)) {

            int letraPosMayus = alphabet.indexOf(coded_letra);
            char tebLetraPosMayus = tebahpla.charAt(letraPosMayus);

            decoded_string = decoded_string+tebLetraPosMayus;
        }
        else {
            int letraPosMinus1 = alphabet1.indexOf(coded_letra);
            char tebLetraPosMinus1 = tebahpla1.charAt(letraPosMinus1);
            decoded_string = decoded_string + tebLetraPosMinus1;
        }

    }
    return decoded_string;
}
```

Comment: Hello. A simple description of what your code does would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: Hey, your answer appears to be in Java… Never confuse JavaScript, they are very different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily convert the code posted by @Robert from Java to Javascript. I've already modified the code to keep the non letter characters (such as white spaces, numbers, punctuation, etc.):

```js
function enAtbash(mensage) {    

    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var tebahpla = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
    var alphabet1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var tebahpla1 = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
    var decoded_string = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < mensage.length; i++) {
        var coded_letra = mensage.charAt(i);
        
 if (/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(mensage[i])) {
  decoded_string = decoded_string+mensage[i]; 
 }
 else if (mensage[i] === mensage[i].toUpperCase()) {
      var letraPosMayus = alphabet.indexOf(coded_letra);
      var tebLetraPosMayus = tebahpla.charAt(letraPosMayus);
      decoded_string = decoded_string+tebLetraPosMayus;
        } else {
      var letraPosMinus1 = alphabet1.indexOf(coded_letra);
      var tebLetraPosMinus1 = tebahpla1.charAt(letraPosMinus1);
      decoded_string = decoded_string + tebLetraPosMinus1;
        }

    }
    return decoded_string;
}

document.write(enAtbash("Hello World!"));
```